# is there an function to extract tags inside a tag and all other remaining tags in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to **scrape** the data from the web page which is in this format . I only need the inner text of h2 and h3's first child i.e from the first span and all other `<p>` tags

```
<div class="info">
   <h2>
      <span>first heading</span>
      <span> not required</span>
   </h2>
   <p> 1 paragraph</p>
   <p> 2 paragraph</p>
 <div> some tags</div>

  <h3>
      <span>second heading</span>
      <span> not required</span>
   </h3>
   <p> 3 paragraph</p>
   <p> 4 paragraph</p>

</div>
```

Outputs;

```
first heading
 1 paragraph
 2 paragraph
second heading
 3 paragraph
 4 paragraph
```

soup.find_all(["h1", "p","h2","h3"])
after trying this I'm also getting the second spans inner text which I don't want.
I need only the inner text of h2 and h3' first span content and p tag content.
I am new to python and soup any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
my_data = [your html above]
soup = bs(my_data, "lxml")

for head in ["h2", "h3"]:
  target = soup.find(head)
  print(target.findChild().text)
```

Output:

```
first heading
second heading
```

Comment: hi jack, sorry but I think this will only print the content of span. My expected output is     first heading  1 paragraph  2 paragraph second heading   3 paragraph 4 paragraph  
 anyway thank you for your help

Comment: @JayakrishnanMR - Sorry, but I don't understand that. Can you edit your question and post the exact desired output?

Comment: hey jack, i have edited the question with my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find_all() to get the tags you want then use findChild() on the elements that you want the first child only

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="info">
   <h2>
      <span>first heading</span>
      <span> not required</span>
   </h2>
   <p> 1 paragraph</p>
   <p> 2 paragraph</p>
 <div> some tags</div>

  <h3>
      <span>second heading</span>
      <span> not required</span>
   </h3>
   <p> 3 paragraph</p>
   <p> 4 paragraph</p>

</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for elem in soup.find_all(['h2', 'h3', 'p']):
    if elem.name == 'p':
        print(elem.text)
    else:
        print(elem.findChild().text)
```

Outputs;

```
first heading
 1 paragraph
 2 paragraph
second heading
 3 paragraph
 4 paragraph
```

Comment: Thank you dan this is exactly what I am looking for  :)